# Read also null from SERIAL with POSIX

Tags: c++, c, serial-port, posix

I have device which uses all char signs to communicate. I know fixed length of transferred messages, and I am using termio.h to communicate with this device. 
The problem is that I can't read whole message when one of signs array is null sign (\0). Read function stops at this moment and my message is incomplete. This is strange because I can write (with function write()) as many null signs as I want.
I know that every string suppose to be null ended but I need to read these null signs, is there a way do do it?
Thanks!

Comment: If you have a fixed size, then `read` that size. The `read` function does not check the data it reads. It's probably your *output* of the data that stops at the zero. However, there's no way of knowing for certain unless you show some code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is almost certainly right.  This is so 'C-style string' bug that it's almost nailed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your serial port in non-canonical mode a below

options.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;

If you don't have this flag, by default serial port is opened in canonical mode.

In non-canonical mode way you will receive "raw" bytes, which I guess is what you need if you

are receiving all kinds of characters.

Comment: My flags:


`se.c_iflag = 0;
se.c_oflag= 0;
se.c_cflag= CS8|V_B115200|PARENB|PARODD|CREAD|CLOCAL ;
se.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
se.c_line= 0;
se.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
se.c_cc[VTIME]  = 0;se.c_iflag = 0;
se.c_oflag= 0;
se.c_cflag= CS8|V_B115200|PARENB|PARODD|CREAD|CLOCAL ;
se.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
se.c_line= 0;
se.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
se.c_cc[VTIME]  = 0; se.c_iflag = 0;
se.c_oflag= 0;
se.c_cflag= CS8|V_B115200|PARENB|PARODD|CREAD|CLOCAL ;
se.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
se.c_line= 0;
se.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
se.c_cc[VTIME]  = 0; `

Comment: Sorry for three times flags repetition, my mistake. With these flags I still can't read whole message.